# Justify inline-blocks in one width

Tags: css

Example HTML:

```
<div id='b'>
    <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
<div id='c'>
    <span>1</span><span>2</span>
</div>

<div id='d'>
    <span>1</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    text-align: center;
}
div span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #999;
    text-align: left;
}
#b{
    padding-left: 60px;
}
#b span{
    margin-left: -60px;
}
#c{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#c span{
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

< span > count is dynamic (up to 10). All span must fit one width in < div >, so if no place left, then negative margin in the place.

How to make it done without #b, #c?

Comment: Yes. But seems I have only one solution: set/change with javascript something like < div data-spans='3' > and in css write for all 10 variants div[data-spans='3'].

Answer (score 2):

Set your `span` elements to display as table cells rather than inline blocks, this way they will always fit on one line within the containing `div`:

```css
div {
    display: table;
}

div span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8B7C4/).

Comment: < span > has predefined width. This is playing cards to understand more close my problem.